# Decoding JSON with Codable works for one call but not another with the same properties

Tags: ios, json, swift, model-view-controller, codable

I am working on a project involving Earthquakes,
I have made a call to this URL of Earthquakes with a magnitude of 4.5 and greater and the Data gets decoded correctly. I see the response on the console: https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_week.geojson

The problem lies when i use another URL: https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_week.geojson . This URL returns the same properties as the above URL but it doesn't decode correctly.

Things i tried:

1. Making the properties of the Response optional
2. Creating a seperate Model for Response

This is what i how is my Model:

```
struct Earthquake: Codable {
let type: String?
let metadata: Metadata?
let features: [Feature]
let bbox: [Double]?

}
// MARK: - Metadata
struct Metadata: Codable {
    let generated: Int
    let url: String
    let title: String
    let status: Int
    let api: String
    let count: Int
}


// MARK: - Feature
struct Feature: Codable {
    let type: String
    let properties: Properties
    let geometry: Geometry
    let id: String?
}

// MARK: - Properties
struct Properties: Codable {
    let mag: Double?
    let place: String?
    let time, updated: Int?
    let tz: Int?
    let url: String?
    let detail: String?
    let felt: Int?
    let cdi, mmi: Double?
    let alert: String?
    let status: String?
    let tsunami, sig: Int?
    let net: String?
    let code, ids: String?
    let sources: String?
    let types: String?
    let nst: Int?
    let dmin: Double?
    let rms: Double
    let gap: Int?
    let magType: String?
    let type: String?
    let title: String?

}

// MARK: - Geometry
struct Geometry: Codable {
    let type: String
    let coordinates: [Double]
}
```

This is how i call it.

```
let topEarthQuakesURL = URL(string: "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_week.geojson")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: topEarthQuakesURL) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data else {return}
    print(data)

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let EarthquakeData = try! decoder.decode(Earthquake.self, from: data)
    print(EarthquakeData.features[0].geometry.coordinates)
}

task.resume()
```

i get this error. Notice that it print's out `1064216 bytes` . Which tells me that i am getting the data, it is just not decoding correctly at one point. Just not sure where.

```
1064216 bytes
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: 
Swift.DecodingError.dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: 
[CodingKeys(stringValue: "features", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 29", intValue:
 29), CodingKeys(stringValue: "properties", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "gap", 
intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Parsed JSON number <231.67> does not fit in Int.", 
underlyingError: nil)): file 
/Users/olerma/Documents/EarthQuakes/Urth/Urth/Controller/MainViewController.swift, line 33
```

Comment: please avoid `try!` specially with JSON responses

Answer (score 1):

> properties -> gap ----- Parsed JSON number <231.67> does not fit in Int.

so change

```
let gap: Int?
```

to

```
let gap: Double?
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you .